# epsilon/delta definition alternative?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

The phrase "any epsilon greater than zero" has always seemed somewhat vague.

Question: is this an equivalent definition?

$\forall\mbox{ Natural Numbers }N>0 \,\,\exists\delta>0\mbox{ s.t. }0<|x−x_0|<δ \implies|f(x)−f(x_0)|<1/N$.

Comment: Yes this is equivalent due to the Archimedean property of the natural numbers. I think we just like our $\varepsilon$.

Comment: In fact, you can just use every second natural number if you want to be more economical...

Comment: And to avoid Greek letters altogether, we can say that for any positive integer $N$ there is a positive integer $Q$ such that whenever whenever $|x-x_0|\lt \frac{1}{Q}$, $\dots$.

Comment: What does second natural number mean?

Comment: He means you can use only even natural numbers: "$\forall$ even natural numbers $N>0$ …"

Comment: But there's nothing vague about "for any $\epsilon > 0$". It means exactly what it says. You want to use $\epsilon = 1/100$ ? Go ahead. You want to use $\epsilon = 3.14159265358979…$? Go ahead. You want to use $\epsilon = .00000000000000000000000008043759086094098349$? Go ahead. You can use ANY positive number whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible alternative to the epsilon, delta definition of continuity is Cauchy's original definition. Namely, $f$ is continuous at $x$ if for every infinitesimal $\alpha$ the difference $f(x+\alpha)-f(x)$ is similarly infinitesimal. See [Cours d'Analyse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cours_d%27Analyse).